# How to check if [Shift + Tab] is being pressed in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qkeyevent

How would one check if the SHIFT key is held and the TAB key is pressed with a QKeyEvent?

I've tried using:

```
(event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab && event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier)
```

However, the `event->key()` is not equal to `Qt::Key_Tab` whenever the shift key is held down.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `event->key()` is printed in hexadecimal format:

```
qDebug()<<QString("key: 0x%1").arg(event->key(), 8, 16, QChar('0'));
```

you get what: `"key: 0x01000002"` then checking in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) and you see that the key is:

```
Qt::Key_Backtab 0x01000002
```

So you have to use that key:

```
if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab)
```